# Find limit of sequence $d_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble computing the limit of a sequence $d_n$, supposing it's convergent:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} d_n := \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\left(\frac{(-1)^n\pi}2\right)$$

Comment: **Hint:** What can you say about the subsequences $d_{2n}$ and $d_{2n+1}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit does not exist, because $\sin\left(\frac {(-1)^n \pi}2\right)$ is alternating with $1$ and $-1$. But we have two convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 0):

The given series an oscilating series and has two limit points 1 and -1. This means that a unique limit doesnt exist and hence it is not convergent